# SQL joining tables twice

Tags: sql

I want to create a query that determines the number of items purchased per month per customer.

Below simplified the table structure:

```
INVOICES
- ID
- INVNO (Invoice Number)
- CUSTID (Customer ID)
- INVDATE
- ...

INVOICES_POSITIONS (e.g. 4x Chair)
- ID
- INVID (Invoice ID)
- ARTID (Article ID)
- AMOUNT
- ...

CUSTOMERS
- ID
- NAME
- ...

ARTICELS (e.g. Woodern Chair)
- ID
- ARTNO
- DESCRIPTION
- ...

ARTICLES_MATERIAL
- ID
- ARTID (ID of article, which contains this material - e.g. Woodern table)
- ARTIDCONT (ID of article, of the material consumed (e.g. woodplanks)
- QUANTITY
- ...
```

So my goal is to see how much products are bought per customer per month.

Customer A:

- 12x Wooden Planks (composited by one table (made of 4 planks) and
  four chairs, each 2 planks)
- 50x Nails (composited by one table and four chairs)
- 1x Oil

Now the problem: there are articles that needs some material and others that do not (such as oil).

I tried to combine this restriction via a LEFT JOIN with INNER JOIN, but did not manage it because the article table has to be self joined.

Comment: Some data would be helpful, also the query you've tried?  It's a bit difficult to follow the question

Comment: You might want to consider doing this in a stored procedure and creating a temporary table that sums up the quantity of material articles (nails used in chairs, etc.) then summing that with the articles shown directly on the invoice (nails purchased separately from chairs, or the chairs themselves).

Comment: If you want help with this you’ve got to give us some sample data as @miked says.